# IP Regex in case

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a case statement that checks the arguments given and if its an IP to connect to it. I am having trouble verifying the IP.

```
case $1 in
-h)
    echo "usage: $0 <IP/DNS/IP range> <Port/Portrange>";
    ;;
--help)
    echo "usage: $0 <IP/DNS/IP range> <Port/Portrange>";
    ;;
    [1-255].[0-255].[0-255].[0-255] )
```

The regex above is working just for `1.1.1.1` or same IPs.

Comment: DRY: use `-h | --help )` if they have the same action.

Comment: besides, case supports only wildcard, not regex, AFAIK.

Comment: Any idea how can i make a wildcard that will make the difference betweekn an ip ( *.*.*.*) and an ip range ? (*.*.*.*-*.*.*.*)

Answer (score 4):

The character class defines a single character. Thus `[1-255]` matches a single character in the range 1-2, or 5, or 5 (again, sic).

The proper fix if you want to stick to `case` syntax is to weed out the disallowed variants, then fall through to your actual handling.

```
*[!.0-9]* | *.*.*.*.* | .* | *. | *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]* \
  | *2[6-9][0-9]* | *25[6-9]* )
    error ;;
# require three dots
*.*.*.* ) ... Success scenario ... ;;
* ) error ;;
```

(I'm sure there's some corner case I have overlooked still.)

To simplify the code, perhaps you could use a variable `realip=false` and set it to `true` in the success scenario, then do a simple `if $realip` after the `esac` and keep the code inside the `case` as simple as possible.

By the by, the patterns supported by `case` are glob patterns, not true regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you tripleee. But doing this won't let me use this command with a hostname or ip range, right ?

Comment: Right, but then do you need to check for a valid IP? Just let the resolver deal with the user input, and exit if it fails.